# My AdMob Ad only loading up when I navigate to another page then back

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob, ads

Is this because of the OnElementChanged event?

Can I load the ads when the app is starting?

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var adView = new AdView(Context);
            switch ((Element as AdBanner).Size)
            {
                case AdBanner.Sizes.Standardbanner:
                    adView.AdSize = AdSize.Banner;
                    break;
                ...
            }

            adView.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx";

            var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            adView.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());

            SetNativeControl(adView);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I able to solve same issue by setting the VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" and HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"

Answer (score 0):

To create a native control in `OnElementChanged` in a [renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view), test on `e.NewElement != null` and `Control == null`:

```
base.OnElementChanged(e); 

if (e.NewElement != null && Control == null) 
{   
    _adView = CreateNativeControl(...);
    SetNativeControl(_adView); 
}
```

According to the [renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) documentation, the `OnElementChanged` method "is called when the Xamarin.Forms custom control is created to render the corresponding native control".

Answer (score 0):

When the App is calling the OnElementChanged method at the start of the program it doesn’t showing up any ads. Only when it called to the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the reason to issue happens, but after a doze of tries I  found a workaround that worked for me, I did put the below code in end of OnAppearing override:

```cs
if (!this.initialized)
{
    this.initialized = true;
    this.adMobView.IsVisible = false;

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => this.adMobView.IsVisible = true);
    });
}
```

Basically, I change the visibility of admob view to false and, after some time (test good delay values for you), I change it to true again.

That is far away from a good solution and a best one will be very welcome, but for now it worked for me and can be usefull temporarily.