# How do I ensure my Google AdMob control is visible on page load?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, admob

I'm writing my first mobile Xamarin.Forms app in Visual Studio using ContentPages linked to ViewModels. Everything about the app works as expected - the data comes in from API and gets displayed, navigation works, and the Google AdMob test ad **does** show up - but the latter only happens once the user has interacted with the page in some way.

I've spent all day reading and trying different things - adding calls to OnAppearing, invoking the PropertyChanged event, assigning visibility, using different methods of inheritance, and nothing has worked so far.

This is what's displayed on page load:

[image]

This is what's displayed once I've interacted with the 'Use My Location' button:

[image]

So I'm definitely getting an ad, but only after I click something.

The same is true of the content on the About page.

I can also make the ad appear if I change properties of the <ads:AdBanner... /> control in either of the .xaml files. For example, changing the HorizontalOptions property from 'CenterAndExpand' to 'End' in Browse.xaml will cause the ad control to appear. If I then navigate from 'Browse' to 'About' the ad on the About page will not be visible, but if I then change the HorizontalOptions property in the AboutPage.xaml file then the ad control will appear again. If I swap back from 'About' to 'Browse' the ad that was there has now gone again, but will appear if I edit the .xaml.

[image]

So, how do I ensure my Google AdMob control is visible all the time, on every page load/appearance?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on [My AdMob Ad only loading up when I navigate to another page then back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260691/my-admob-ad-only-loading-up-when-i-navigate-to-another-page-then-back)

I also had to set the grid row to a fixed height.

Thanks Jawad Ahmed!